# Flutter_callkit_incoming, Call notification not working in detached mode in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, call, callkit

I am using flutter_callkit_incoming to show call notification in my application.
I am using firebase messaging to receive the notification. It works fine when app is in foreground or when it's just gone in the background but when the app is cleared from apps or it is in detached mode it's not working.

I am using below code to send a notification from the server.

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
    data.token,
    {
      data: data.payload, 
    },
    {
      contentAvailable: true,
    },
  );
```

When I receive above notification in my flutter application, I invoke below function from
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming

```
  FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(callKitParams);
```

I am using callkit params as per documentation, it works when app is in foreground. The only issue it doesn't work when app is in detached state, in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function :

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(
    IncomingCallParams.callParams(
      name: json.decode(message.data['data'])['senderName'],
      meetingId: json.decode(message.data['data'])['data']['meetingId'],
    ),
  );
}
```

To handle notification while app is terminated, we need to call FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage();

Comment: I have been doing the same but now I realized that _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler is not getting called when my iOS app is in terminated state.

Comment: For ios, you have to add some native side code. It's given in the package info on pub.dev.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to what exactly needs to be added, I have followed the exact documentation. It works perfectly if app is not terminated and is resumed in the background.

Comment: Below Get device push token VoIP. iOS: return deviceToken, Android: Empty https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming